# Serving the CSS and JavaScript files of the Bootstrap theme locally

Tags: 8, theming

I have installed bootstrap theme on drupal 8 and instead of using CDN provider, I'd like to load my bootstrap files locally for offline intranet usage.

Does anyone knows where should I put my bootstrap css & js files to in order to achieve this? Are there any instructions I can follow to achieve this?

[image: bootstrap config in D8]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Bootstrap Library](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_library) module.

Quote:

> 1. Download Boostrap files on /libraries/bootstrap (you`ll have to
>      create "libraries" folder in Dr8 install directory).
> 2. Then go to
>      example.com/admin/config/development/bootstrap_library 
>      -configure on which pages you want to load the libraries (by default everything but admin/*).
> 3. Configure on which themes you want to load the libraries.
> 4. Drink some champagne coffee.